# Vue Module parse failed: Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, vue.js

When I install project dependency from local directory

`npm install ../myDep`

and next run `npm run serve` everything is ok.

But when I install this dependency directly from repo

(`npm install git+ssh://(...)/myDep.git`) (it should be done in this way)

and run `npm run serve` I have an error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   }
| 
>   device = {
| 
|     info: () => {
```

Here is part of file with this error:

```
export class MyDependencyClass {

  constructor(args) {
    (...)
  }

  device = {

    info: () => {
      return {};
    },  

    (...)
  }

  (...)
}
```

This unexpected token is `=` and only when I install it from repo.

How can I fix it?

@edit
package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "deploy": "./deploy.sh",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.3.2",
    "myDep": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com:pplaczek/myDep.git",
    "markdown-it-vue": "^1.0.10",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.1.0",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^3.9.97",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ["vuetify"]
};
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"]
};
```

Comment: Please share your `package.json` and `vue.config.js` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee this will help, but you can try with the following Babel configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@vue/app',
      {
        exclude:
        [
          "@babel/plugin-transform-typeof-symbol",
          '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
        ],
        modules: false
      }
    ]
  ],
  plugins:
  [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", // this seems to be the important one
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately this doesn't solve problem

Comment: The error comes because a certain feature of Babel is not (properly) activated - the ability to initialize class properties. Perhaps if you move the initialization inside the constructor - you may be able to work-around the issue.

Comment: You are right, I moved the initialization inside the constructor and it solved error, but code is ugly :/ Whatever thanks for this.